# Trying to create a Gain (Bode) plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to get this code to work and I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I realize that "simple" syntax problems are frowned on here but to us noobs they are NOT simple. (and the explanations in the documentation are often worse than useless -- they might as well be in Etruscan). And this is starting to bug me, no pun intended.

I used a variation on code supplied by [@m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61344/trying-to-get-multiple-curves-on-single-bode-plot/61359?noredirect=1#comment174652_61359) for a similar problem. All I did was change some variable names and try to add the log of a function (or rather, that function's result) to the plot. But I get a blank plot. So here's the code:

```
Remove["Global`*"];
With[{r = 1000, \[ScriptL] = 1, c1 = 0.000001}, 
zc[w_] := 1/(I*w*c1);
zl[w_] := I*w*\[ScriptL];
H[w_] := zl[w]/(zl[w] + zc[w] + r);
 G[H_] := 20*Log[Abs[H]];
 Row[{
   LogLinearPlot[G[H], {w, 10, 2*10^3}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], AxesLabel -> "Gain", 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> 250], 
   LogLinearPlot[Arg@H[w], {w, 10, 2*10^3}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], AxesLabel -> phase, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> 250]}]]
```

I am trying to tease out what's wrong here. The second plot looks fine. The first on is the one that doesn't seem to work, though I get gridlines.

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Please link to the code you used

Comment: I put the code i used in there, what do you mean?

Comment: Change `LogLinearPlot[G[H],...]` to `LogLinearPlot[G[H[w]],...]`.

Comment: @kguler - THANKS. Bloody hell this was driving me crazy. As an aside, someone needs to write "Mathematica for Dummies" soon. :-)

Comment: For two reasons: First, you posted non-working code, and second to give attribution to the original author

Comment: OK. Here's the original question I asked: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61344/trying-to-get-multiple-curves-on-single-bode-plot/61359?noredirect=1#comment174652_61359 and the user was @m_goldberg, who should get credit for fixing my original problem, yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With[{ r = 1000, ll = 1, c1 = 0.000001,
       opts = {GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], 
               LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> 250}}, 
 zc[w_] := 1/(I*w*c1);
 zl[w_] := I*w*ll;
 H[w_]  := zl[w]/(zl[w] + zc[w] + r);
 G[w_]  := 20*Log[Abs[H[w]]];
 Row[{
   LogLinearPlot[G[w], {w, 10, 2*10^3},     opts, AxesLabel -> "Gain"], 
   LogLinearPlot[Arg@H[w], {w, 10, 2*10^3}, opts, AxesLabel -> "Phase"]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Are you using version 9?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, still there

Answer (score 1):

Alternative modifications of your code to make it work as expected (second plot omitted):

```
ClearAll[zl, H, G, r, w];
With[{r = 1000, \[ScriptL] = 1, c1 = 0.000001}, zc[w_] := 1/(I*w*c1);
 zl[w_] := I*w*\[ScriptL];
 H[w_] := zl[w]/(zl[w] + zc[w] + r);
 G[H_] := 20*Log[Abs[H]];
 LogLinearPlot[G[H[w]], {w, 10, 2*10^3}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], AxesLabel -> "Gain", 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> 250]]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[zl, H, G, r, w];
With[{r = 1000, \[ScriptL] = 1, c1 = 0.000001}, zc[w_] := 1/(I*w*c1);
 zl[w_] := I*w*\[ScriptL];
 H = zl[w]/(zl[w] + zc[w] + r);
 G[H_] := 20*Log[Abs[H]];
 LogLinearPlot[G[H], {w, 10, 2*10^3}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], AxesLabel -> "Gain", 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> 250]]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[zl, H, G, r, w];
With[{r = 1000, \[ScriptL] = 1, c1 = 0.000001}, zc[w_] := 1/(I*w*c1);
 zl[w_] := I*w*\[ScriptL];
 H[w_] := zl[w]/(zl[w] + zc[w] + r);
 G[H_] := 20*Log[Abs[H[w]]];
 LogLinearPlot[G[H], {w, 10, 2*10^3}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], AxesLabel -> "Gain", 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> 250]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks this also helps. I am finding this whole process maddening sometimes. (Some of it is just me getting old I suspect. I haven't done programming since BASIC and Pascal were a thing).

Comment: Jesse, you are not alone ... and, thanks to sites like Mathematica.SE, such frustrations are a little easier to cope with than the good/old Pascal/Basic days:)

Comment: Are you also using version 9?  My grid lines don't look like that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yes I am still on Version 9.