# Trying to get plots to work AGAIN

Tags: plotting

OK, I have asked stuff here before. I am probably driving people crazy but this is making me angry and frustrated. And yes, I bet this is some simple syntax thing but I can't figure it out and I am at the point where I need stuff to freaking WORK.

Here's the problem: I am trying to get this thing to plot. I even used a variation on code given when I asked about this before:

[Trying to create a Gain (Bode) plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64182/trying-to-create-a-gain-bode-plot)

All I want to do is alter the  response function. That is ALL. And I can't make it work. All I get is a blank plot. I have been going through this step by step to make sure I don't change much. All I did was alter the variable names and the function. This should not be so  difficult. I change the function I want to plot and BAM no more plots.

Here's the code in question:

```
With[{R = 1000, L = 1, c1 = 0.000001},
  Zc[ω_] := 1/(I*ω*c1);
  ZL[ω_] := I*ω*L;
  Ztot[ω_] := Zc[ω] + ZL[ω];
  H[ω_] := Ztot[ω]/(R + Ztot[ω]);
  H1[H[ω_]] := Abs[H[ω]];
  G[H1] := Log[H1[H]];
  {LogLogPlot[{G[H1_]}, {ω, 10, 2*10^3}, GridLines -> Automatic,
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], AxesLabel -> Abs[H], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> 250]}]
```

I can't seem to figure out whether it wants variable names with underscores or whatever. The "manual" is zero help. Can someone tell me why this keeps happening to me? I am at my wit's end.

Comment: [DefiningFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)

Comment: I read that part of the doc. It was little help. A general overview is all very well but this is a rather different problem I have.

Comment: How can it be indeterminate? The value R is a constant, there's no way to get a division by zero error at 10^3. What do you mean?

Comment: I still can't figure out what you are talking about. There's no G[10^3] necessarily...

Comment: My plot domain is the gain (the log I want to plot on the vertical axis. It should change with omega. (w). I still have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

The first is that the definition of `G` doesn't match because the intermediate functions already evaluate before `G` does. `H1` has the same issue. You can fix that with `SetAttributes[G,HoldFirst]` as shown below.

The next problem is that the function you are asking to plot is `G`, not `G[H1[H[omega]]]`, which is not the same thing.

The third problem is that when you fix these things up, your function is indeed `Indeterminate` at $\omega \geq 1000$. I don't know why, but you can check it yourself using `G[H1[H[999]]]` versus `G[H1[H[1000]]]`.

The final problem is that when your function is defined, it's negative, so  `LogLogPlot` doesn't show anything. You want `LogLinearPlot`.

Here is a fixed up version.

```
With[{R = 1000, L = 1, c1 = 0.000001}, 
 Zc[ω_] := 1/(I*ω*c1); SetAttributes[G, HoldFirst]; 
 SetAttributes[H1, HoldFirst];
 ZL[ω_] := I*ω*L;
 Ztot[ω_] := Zc[ω] + ZL[ω];
 H[ω_] := Ztot[ω]/(R + Ztot[ω]);
 H1[H[ω_]] := Abs[H[ω]];
 G[H1[H_]] := Log[H1[H]];
 LogLinearPlot[{G[H1[H[ω]]]}, {ω, 10, 999}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed],
   AxesLabel -> Abs[H], LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], 
  ImageSize -> 250]]
```

[image]

Comment: And @Jesse, I get that it can be frustrating learning a new language, especially one as strange and particular as Mathematica, but please, cut out the foul language. It's not appropriate to this site and is unnecessary. I can't believe that this is probably the answer that will kick me over the 20,000 rep points line.

Comment: I kicked you :D

Comment: And there it is!

Comment: @Verbeia sorry about the foul language, that's why I typewriter-cussed. AN thanks a whole lot for the help. But I want to understand -- I was trying to define the functions in order I was using them. What does SetAttribtes do? (the manual is not much help for those of us who speak ordinary human languages :-) )

Comment: @Verbeia Congratulations on becoming a Trusted User!  Although that title is pretty funny for a ♦. :^)